# How can I check a string multiple times for certain pattern?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string (a source code of a website). And I want to check for a string multiple times. I currently use this code:

```
string verified = "starting";
if (s.Contains(verified))
{
    int startIndex = s.IndexOf(verified);
    int endIndex = s.IndexOf("ending", startIndex);
    string verifiedVal = s.Substring(startIndex + verified.Length, (endIndex - (startIndex + verified.Length)));
    imgCodes.Add(verifiedVal);
}
```

The code does work, but it only works for the first string found. There are more than 1 appearances in the string, so how can I find them all and add them to the list?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to find only occurs or you want index of each occurs?

Comment: @PareshGami I only want to find the values between "starting" and "ending". There is more than one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex to do that:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"starting(?<content>(?:(?!ending).)*)");
imgCodes.AddRange(matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["content"].Value));
```

After that `imgCodes` will contain ALL substrings between `starting` and `ending`.

Sample:

```
var s = "afjaöklfdata-entry-id=\"aaa\" data-page-numberuiwotdata-entry-id=\"bbb\" data-page-numberweriouw";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"data-entry-id=""(?<content>(?:(?!"" data-page-number).)+)");
var imgCodes = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["content"].Value).ToList();
// imgCode = ["aaa", "bbb"] (as List<string> of course)
```

If you don't need empty strings you can change `.)*` in Regex to `.)+`.

Comment: Is this work for nested expression like "startingXstartingYendingXending"?

Comment: No. `s.IndexOf(...)` will also fail for nested strings. It is possible to create a regex to handle nested expressions but the question is what value should be added to `imgCodes` in the case of the outer match.

Comment: If I were to use `data-entry-id="` for starting and `" data-page-number` for ending, how can I do this? I tried replacing `starting` and `ending`, but it doesn't work. Sorry about that, I'm new with Regex.

Comment: I changed the sample code for your starting and ending.

Comment: @Verarind I have one question, might be a little too late, but for some reason it doesn't seem to add the last match to the list. I am using the exact code except with `.+?`.

Comment: @user5204184 Hm. Are you sure that the ending pattern is fully present for the last match? I tested it without problems. All matches are added to the list. Sounds strange. Tomorrow I'll test it one more time.

Comment: @user5204184 Is there any empty item? If so the regex will fail because it consumes the first character of the ending pattern. I'll create a solution.

Comment: @user5204184 I changed the solution that empty items are handled correctly. ... But I couldn't reproduce the last item problem. Sorry. Do you have any more code for testing?

Comment: @Verarind It was a problem on my end, your code works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "abc123djhfh123hfghh123jkj12";
        string v = "123";
        int index = 0;
        while (s.IndexOf(v, index) >= 0)
        {
            int startIndex = s.IndexOf(v, index);
            Console.WriteLine(startIndex);
            //do something with startIndex
            index = startIndex + v.Length ;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the use of the ending pattern and code that extracts the string between starting and ending.